# Page Transition inside a frame in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I would like to ask how to add a transition (sliding from Left to right) from my main page, and when I hit back button at my second page I would also add a transition (Sliding from Left to right) to my other page, how can I do that?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Inventory.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainPage" Height="643" Width="715" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="Images/ad2eecf5e5ca5f2b98ba56f77efaa972.ico">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace Inventory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainFrame.Navigate(new MainPage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Developing view transitions from scratch is no easy feat, but luckily enough, there are pre-written libraries that can do this for us. The best that I have found so far is called `Transitionals`. You can download the dll from the [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) page at CodePlex.

Comment: That library doesn't do slide transitions, it's all in place transitions.

Comment: It *does* do slide transitions, along with a wide variety of other Powerpoint style transitions. I know because I've used them, so unless they have created a new version with less than the old version which is *very* unlikely, I would say that you're mistaken.

Comment: Do you mind telling me which transition to use? I downloaded the preview app and went through them all.

Comment: I don't have my test code here, but I'll try to remember to take a look when I get home. Just to be absolutely clear, are you referring to a *slide* transition as one view sliding in from the left (or right) and covering the previous view?

Comment: When I say slide I mean as if you had 3 images side by side like a ribbon and the transition from one to the other is the whole ribbon moving, so half way in between you'd see half of two slides.

Comment: Ah... in that case, I take back my above comments, it doesn't have that kind of functionality... but that's easy to implement yourself in WPF. Just put your `Image`s into a `Canvas` and apply a `TranslateTransform` to their `RenderTransform` properties and animate to move them.

Comment: The issue is that I'd like to implement a sort of wizard using the navigation source where the transition is a slide. There's an example of how to do it, but it's not complete and in my opinion seems overly complicated for wpf.